# HTTP Error when using urllib.request

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do a profanity check test. The code I have written so far is

```
import urllib.request  

def read_text ():
    file = open (r"C:\Users\Kashif\Downloads\abc.txt")
    file_print = file.read ()
    print (file_print)
    file.close ()
    check_profanity (file_print)

def check_profanity (file_print):
    connection = urllib.request.urlopen ("http://www.purgomalum.com/service/containsprofanity?text="+file_print)
    output = connection.read ()
    print ("The Output is "+output)
    connection.close ()
    read_text ()
```

But I get the error below

> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

I don't know what I am going wrong.

I am using Python 3.6.1

Comment: you should include the stack trace from the error.

Comment: Please also include the contents of abc. Probably there is some issues in the file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP error you're getting is usually a sign of something bad in the way you are requesting data to the server. According to the [HTTP Spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.1):

> **400 Bad Request**
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
> syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications

In concrete in your example, the problem seems to be with the lack of URL encoding of the data you're sending in the URL. You should try using the method `quote_plus` from the [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus) module to make your request acceptable:

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

...

encoded_file_print = quote_plus(file_print)
url = "http://www.purgomalum.com/service/containsprofanity?text=" + encoded_file_print
connection = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

If that doesn't work then the problem might be with the contents of your file. You can try it first with a simple example, to verify your script works and then try using the file's content afterwards.

Apart from the above, there's also a couple of other issues with your code:

1. No spaces needed between methods and brackets: `file.close ()` or `def read_text ():` and so on.
2. Decode the content after reading it to convert bytes to a string: `output = connection.read().decode('utf-8')`
3. The way you're calling the methods creates a circular dependency. `read_text` calls `check_profanity` that in the end calls `read_text` that calls `check_profanity`, etc. Remove the extra method calls and just use `return` to return the output of a method:

   ```
   content = read_text()
   has_profanity = check_profanity(content)
   print("has profanity? %s" % has_profanity)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, it works perfectly. I just have another question. I have seen this same program working perfectly in python 2.7. Are the changes you mentioned due to the change in version? I am completely beginner therefore I don't know much

Comment: Hm I don't think so. The changes I made with using `quote_plus` were necessary for the request to be correctly sent to the server. I don't see how this could work differently on Python 2.7. If you have that code around send it and I can try it out